# Problems Accessing Public Data on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the graph on Facebook to query basic user information (I used it to get a users username) used to be public. i.e:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me
```

It used to return public, basic, information on my account. Now when I try it, it's asking me for an access token.

When did this change? And do I now need an access token to pull any public data from Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an access token with it.

The `ACCESS_TOKEN` can be obtained from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer (click on the `get-token` button)

This access code has to be replaced by the "ACCESS_TOKEN" in the following URL :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```